# AssemblyLoaderHelper not resolving

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

My program has the ability to download new DLLs and restart itself as a self-updater. I'm trying to add some checks, like "before replacing this DLL, make sure it has class X and method Y".

I'm trying to use AssemblyLoaderHelper for this. My implementation matches other examples across the internet, seen here: https://gist.github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/29f930aa267ff8bea292715467b0f40a

To use it,

```
        var loadContext = new AssemblyLoaderHelper(dllDirectory);
        var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);
        Assembly assembly = loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);
```

dllDirectory definitely exist, and dllFile is contained within it, but LoadFromAssemblyName() always returns null.

Am i doing something wrong?  i could also ask, is there a better way to check a DLL for the existence of a class/method? I don't need to execute anything from the DLL. i can't use just Assemmbly.Load() because i already have another version loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use LoadFileFromAssemblyName for the same reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflection only assembly loading in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803773/reflection-only-assembly-loading-in-net-core)

Comment: @Joshua interesting, i didn't  know about MetadataLoadContext. i got mine working but thanks for the link! i may use it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so turns out AssemblyDependencyResolver wants the path to a dll, not the dll's directory (so c:\plugins\myDll.dll NOT c:\plugins). seems weird since you can use this to load multiple  DLLs, but whatever. it works!

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't just give you _the copy you have already loaded_? That's usually what happens when you try to load an already loaded assembly.

Comment: Yeah, AssemblyLoadContext loads DLLs into their own context, much like AppDomains used to work.